# SQL join using UNION ALL with some columns common and some outer

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, union-all

I would like to make the following join, which is some sort of `UNION ALL` in SQL. How to do it? Preferably how to do it by selecting **all columns** form t1 and t2 and declaring matching keys? I would like to avoid specifying column names if it is possible.

**Update.** I put some values in columns to be more specific. This is what I want:

**Join 1**

[image: union all]

Probably I got answers for this:

**Join 2**

[image: full outer]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Looks like you need a full outer join, possibly with filtering.

Comment: Are C4 and C5 in the output table from table 2?

Comment: I corrected the column names

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin updated my answer to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a full outer join, like so:

```
select *
from table1 t1 
full outer join table2 t2
on t1.c4 = t2.c1 and t1.c5 = t2.c2
```

While SQL Server supports full outer joins, MySQL does not. This query can be rewritten in that situation as follows:

```
select *
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2
on t1.c4 = t2.c1 and t1.c5 = t2.c2
union
select *
from table1 t1 
right outer join table2 t2
on t1.c4 = t2.c1 and t1.c5 = t2.c2
```

Based on your **updated** requirements, the form of this join specified above can be used with slight modifications like so:

```
select null,null,null,t.* from table1 s
right outer join table2  t on s.c4 = t.c1  and s.c5 = t.c2
union
select s.*,null,null from table1 s
left outer join table2  t on s.c4 = t.c1  and s.c5 = t.c2
```

Note that you will still need to include the literal value `null` in your select clause, once for each column that needs to be defaulted to null.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/OVJZC84778)

Comment: I have corrected the column names in the question picture so that it is more consistent now.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Assuming C4 and C5 in your output example are from t2...

```
SELECT t1.C1, t1.C2, t1.C3, t2.C3, t2.C4
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.C4 = t2.C1 AND t1.C5 = t2.C2
```

Comment: I do not think your answer is good. In results I should have a table with 7+4 rows. In your answer this would be possible only if the key do not match. If all values of C1 and C2 of table2 are in table1 then the number of rows in Results will be 7 as in table1.